# use variable as column name in where clause in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to use a variable as column name in my SQL query.

**Problem:**

I can not use dynamic SQL as the SQL query that I have is inside of a user defined inline table function.

So, 
  1. Can not use dynamic SQL 
  2. Can not replace this function with a stored procedure as this is to be called from user defined functions only

What are other possible alternatives?

My code is as follows:

```
create function MatchStringPercent(@parameterFromUser nvarchar(20), @parameterInTable nvarchar(20))
RETURNS table As Return 
SELECT Top(1)
cast(LEN(@parameterInTable) as float)/(Abs(LEN(@parameterFromUser) - LEN(@parameterInTable)) + LEN(@parameterInTable))* 100 As Match
FROM Demo
WHERE @parameterInTable = LEFT( @parameterFromUser , LEN(@parameterInTable) ) 
ORDER BY LEN(@parameterInTable) DESC 
Go
```

Note: This is a repost. I did ask this question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91050/use-variable-as-column-name-in-where-clause-in-sql) and was told this is not possible. May be. but just wanted to know if there is any damn possible alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only real option is a giant `case` statement:

```
where (case when @parameterInTable = 'col1' then col1
            when @parameterInTable = 'col2' then col2
            . . .
       end) = . . .
```

Unfortunately, the cleaner solution is to use dynamic SQL and you can't do this from a function.

I did once see some strange mechanism where a function can call xp_cmdshell, then using a cmd_shell to execute the dynamic SQL, and then doing the work in the command shell.  Functions *are* allowed to run extended stored procedures.  I highly, highly discourage you from going in that direction.  It is way too complicated, it might stop working at some point, and it requires fiddling with permissions that might make your system more vulnerable.

EDIT:

You probably want a slightly more complicated expression (I didn't realize the parameter was on the right side as well as the left):

```
where ( (@parameterInTable = 'col1' and col1 = LEFT(@parameterFromUser , LEN(col1)) ) or
        (@parameterInTable = 'col2' and col2 = LEFT(@parameterFromUser , LEN(col2)) ) or
        . . .
      )
```

or using the `case`:

```
where @parameterFromUser like
       (case when @parameterInTable = 'col1' then col1
             when @parameterInTable = 'col2' then col2
            . . .
        end) + '%';
```

Comment: It works with single statement but gives incorrect syntax near , before the next when at every statement.What might be the reason?